# Swift 3: Wrong UIView size read

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3

I have an UIView that is set to be 50x50 sized in interface builder.

After the view is loaded in the app, it looks perfectly fine, but when I print its size after it get's loaded

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    print(self.frame.height)
}
```

it returns 1000.0

This error has not occurred until I updated my project to Swift 3.0

Anybody got any idea what might have changed? Why printing it's height return 1000.0 while it's actually 50.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the UIView has not set to 50x50 at that point in life circle. At this point it's `1000.0` - a standard size.

The circle is:

```
init    
UIViewController awakeFromNib
loadView
UIView awakeFromNib
UIViewController viewDidLoad
viewWillAppear
viewDidAppear
```

From then on properties like the size are available to work with.

You need to use the layoutIfNeeded property to have access to the layout early.

```
self.layoutIfNeeded()
layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2.0
layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: Ok, that's what I was thinking, but what method should I use then inside UIView implementation to get it right?

Comment: you could hard set the height by `self.frame.height = 50` in awakeFromNib to use it from there on

Comment: or you use the height after viewDidAppear

Comment: So basically there's no way to access the evaluated property inside UIView implementation, I have to do all that stuff inside viewController?

Comment: yes correct. since the properties of the size aren't set before the view is actually called.

Comment: Well, I put it inside CellForARow... and still return 1000.0, that's not the case apparently

Comment: how and when do you populate the CellForARow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124097/discussion-between-david-seek-and-dcdc).